# Volumes of separated meshes in Paraview?

Tags: paraview

I'm working with a researcher who has data of many "droplets" and would like to understand the volume enclosed within each in Paraview. To simplify the problem I made this obj file with two slightly deformed cubes. Is there a way in paraview to get the enclosed volumes of each of these separated (non overlapping) meshes?

[image]

This is slightly different than another post  [which is focusing on a single mesh volume estimation.](https://discourse.paraview.org/t/compute-volume-of-polygonal-mesh-volume-enclosed-by-the-surface/10880/4)

I originally posted the question here, but didn't simplify it enough and haven't heard from anyone just yet. https://discourse.paraview.org/t/estimating-volume-of-separated-surfaces-plotting-histogram/12005

Comment: Connectivity + ExtractSelection to separate the mesh, then this is a duplicate of https://discourse.paraview.org/t/compute-volume-of-polygonal-mesh-volume-enclosed-by-the-surface/10880/4

Comment: Great! I'll try this and then post solution to the situation on the original discourse link. There's also more information added there by Kenneth Moreland and Spiros Tsalikis